# How can I use Tracker.autorun in a static non-Meteor page?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze, meteor-tracker

Some of the pages of my site are server-side rendered so the usual bundle of Meteor JavaScript is not available to them.

We want to keep page size down, but use `Tracker.autorun` for light-weight reactivity, how can we use this piece of Meteor a-la-carte ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have isolated Tracker and all of its dependencies down to a single library you can refer to here:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.chicagogrooves.com/js/meteor-reactive-packages.js

This gives you `Tracker`, `ReactiveDict`, `ReactiveVar`, and their dependencies `EJSON` and `Base64` in a single library (41Kb raw unminified, 11Kb gzipped). The only dependency I did not include is UnderscoreJS, as you may want to source that from a CDN.

Thus, code like this is available to any webpage, even `about:blank`!

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var s = "The name is " + reactiveObject.getName();
  console.log(s);
});
```

Have fun exploring with this here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chicagogrooves/9y49s6so/)

Comment: Nice! Thought about publishing the package on Atmosphere?

Comment: It might be better suited as a bower or npm package, having no server-side part, and I'd love to hear from MDG if they'd support that or do it themselves. But yes, hosting from my S3 bucket is definitely short-term :)